# Generating random filenames in ffmpeg output

Tags: string, shell, random, ffmpeg

hello guys I am using ffmpeg to output different output filenames. By some googling, I did find a command to generate random strings in shell. I used tha in my own command like this:

```
ffmpeg -f concat -i gif-list.txt -c copy cat /dev/urandom | tr -dc 'a-zA-Z0-9' | fold -w 32 | head -n 1.mp4
```

But this is not working. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

You obviously want to evaluate the expression for the destination filename, so in shell this would be done like that:

```
ffmpeg -f concat -i gif-list.txt -c copy \
    $( cat /dev/urandom | tr -dc 'a-zA-Z0-9' | fold -w 32 | head -n 1 ).mp4
```

Alternatively you can use backquotes

```
 `
```

in place of `$(` as well as `)` but IMHO the parentheses are better to be recognized.

Comment: Can be shortened to `$(tr -dc A-Za-z0-9 </dev/urandom | head -c 32)`.